# app and request instance in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying these codes and see that if I remove the default arguments (`request=request, app=app`) from the function `save_files` and `save_file` then the code does not work as expect (the python interpreter does not enter to the function save_file). Why?

```
    def save_files(request=request, app=app):
        "Save all files in a request to the app's upload folder."
        for _, filestorage in request.files.iteritems():
            # Workaround: larger uploads cause a dummy file named '<fdopen>'.
            # See the Flask mailing list for more information.
            if filestorage.filename not in (None, 'fdopen', '<fdopen>'):
                save_file(filestorage, app=app)

    def save_file(filestorage, app=app):
        "Save a Werkzeug file storage object to the upload folder."
        filename = secure_filename(filestorage.filename)
        filepath = os.path.join(app.config['PICTURE_FOLDER'], filename)
        filestorage.save(filepath)

    @app.route('/_add_picture', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def add_picture():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            save_files()
            return 'Uploaded'
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('add_picture.html')
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: yes, but if I remove request=request and app=app in save_files, app=app in save_file, it does not work anymore and I don't know why

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you remove them?

Comment: This is not the big problem because I just want to understand the mecanism. What is not normal is that when I debug with pydev, it executes save_files but in the line save_file, pydev does not jump into the function and it exits...

Comment: I removed it, and it worked fine.

Comment: never mind, maybe it's my Aptana and pydev problem, thanks for investigating!